# MariaDB on Windows - remote connect fails

Tags: windows, mariadb

"Access denied for user 'test'@'' (using password: YES)

I have installed MariaDB on Linux many times, easy to get a remote connection. However, using the same steps on Windows results in rejected remote connection.

I already performed `GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'test'@'%' identified by 'password'`;

Firewall is off. (Firewall error would likely not result in the above error message anyway).

I tried fiddling with my.ini to no avail. (current content below) bind-address=0.0.0.0 did not work.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.11/data
port=3306
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8180M

[client]
port=3306
plugin-dir=C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.11/lib/plugin
```

Comment: I'd just add skip-name-resolve to the config file, to mysqld section. On some reason, the DNS name resolution does not work on this machine, or for that specific IP.